# Proof Verification: Dimension of the subset of $2\times3$ matrix with rank at most 1 is 4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, solution-verification, self-learning

The problem is taken from Gathmann 2.33, from this [link](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/de/alggeom.php)

Let $X$ be the set of all $2 \times 3$ matrices over a field $K$ that have rank at most $1$, considered as a subset of $\mathbb{A}^6 = Mat(2\times 3,K)$. Show that $X$ is an irreducible affine variety. What is its dimension?

There are several threads for this, but their approach is different than mine (invoking projective variates), and due to the location of this problem in the book, I am looking for a basic solution.

I have solved the irreducibility part. However, I am not sure about the dimension proof (I am sure that it is $4$, though).

It is easy to see that it is equal to finding the dimension of $Z(ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd) \subset \mathbb{A}^6$. My strategy is to prove that $k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/\left<ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd\right> \cong k[p,q,r,s]$, which then the dimension is obviously $4$. The irreducibility part shows that $\left<ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd\right>$ is prime.

To do this, I construct a homomorphism $\phi' : k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/  \rightarrow k[p,q,r,s]$ that sends $a$ to $p$, $b$ to $q$, $c$ to $r$, $d$ to $sp$, $e$ to $sq$ and $f$ to $sr$. Because $ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd$ are all in the kernel of this homomorphism by a direct check, this induces a homomorphism $\phi : k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/\left<ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd\right>  \rightarrow k[p,q,r,s]$ so that if $q$ is the quotient projection, $\phi \circ q = \phi'$. Also, consider the homomorphism $\tau' : k[p,q,r,s]/  \rightarrow k[a,b,c,d,e,f]$ that sends  $p$ to $a$, $q$ to $b$, $r$ to $c$ and $s$ to $1$. Then, $\tau = q \circ \tau'$ is a homomorphism between $k[p,q,r,s]$ and $k[a,b,c,d,e,f]/\left<ae-bd,bf-ce,af-cd\right>$. By universal property, they must be inverses of each other, hence they are isomorphic. We conclude that the dimension is equal to $k[p,q,r,s]$, which is just 4.

Please comment on potential flaws/mistakes, and suggest a direction to correctness. Also, I would like some insight on understanding the intuition of dimension and connecting it to Krulls's dimension. Several sample problems similar with this question are also appreciated. Have a nice day!

Comment: Your two maps that you describe are not mutually inverse: the map $\phi$ is not surjective, because $s$ is not in the image. (In fact, these two rings are not isomorphic - one is regular, one isn't.)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. My intuition (which is very rough) is to first see that $\dim k[a,b,c,d,e,f] = 6$. When we mod out $<ae-bd>$, the dim goes down to 5. When we add the prime ideal $<bf-ce>$, the dimension will also go down by 4 as it does not vanish on an irreducible component. However, when we add $af-cd$, it should be decreasing as $af-cd$ is true when $ae-bd = 0$, $bf-ce = 0$ and $be \neq 0$. Hence, it kind of did not add any info, hence the $\dim$ is 4. I am kinda using a Krull Principal Ideal Theorem, but not sure how to formalize.  @KReiser